# php cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to use a cookie with authentication.

This page works once entering user and pass

```
   <?
    if ((!$_POST[username]) || (!$_POST[password])) {
        header("Location: show_login.html");
        exit;
    }
    $db_name = "testDB";
    $table_name = "auth_users";
    $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE username ='$_POST[username]' AND password = password('$_POST[password]')";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($num != 0) {
            $cookie_name = "auth";
            $cookie_value = "ok";
            $cookie_expire = "0";
            $cookie_domain = "domain.com.au";
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookis_value, $cookie_expire, "/", $cookie_domain, 0);
            $display_block = "
            <p><strong>Secret Menu:</strong></p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=\"secretA.php\">secret page A</a>
                <li><a href=\"secretB.php\">secret page B</a>
            </ul>"; 
        } else {
            header("Location: show_login.html");
            exit;
        }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Secret Area</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <? echo "$display_block"; ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

WHen clicking on either secretA.php or secretB.php I am redirected to log in again, it should work. here is the code.
secretB.php

```
<?php

if ($_COOKIE[auth] == "ok") {
    $msg = "<p>Welcome to secret page B, authorised user! </P>";
} else {
    header( "Location: /show_login.html");
    exit;
}
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Secret Page B:</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<? echo "$msg"; ?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: In `secretB.php` do `var_dump($_COOKIE)` and post result here.

Comment: is there a way without doing this, as I am working of some examples from a book which doesnt use any more code then this

Comment: This `var_dump` will check if any cookies are set.

Comment: if this code come from some book, this book is just terrible. This code is full of errors, every line has it. You would better to find yourself another book.

Comment: care to correct thoese errors?

Comment: I am talking not of errors but of the book. it is no problem to correct these errors, but your book may contain ten times more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that may have messed you up...

`setcookie($cookie_name,`**`$cookis_value`**`, $cookie_expire, "/", $cookie_domain, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

This if the great example of bad code.
Thanks for posting it. Many people can read it and learn from this.

Let me explain.
PHP can help you to find some obscure errors. Not every one but some of them.
For example, if you mistyped a variable name, PHP will throw an error... of course if you let PHP to say.
To make every error visible, error reporting level must be maxed.
To do it, every script must contain this line:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

after you add it, if it was properly written code, you would see only one error message pointing to the mistyped variable.
But.
Instead you will see a waterfall of errors. 
Because PHP cannot distinguish intentional errors from occasional ones.

Thus.
It must be no intentional errors in the code, to let you see occasional ones.
This is the great lesson worth to remember.

What are these errors?

1. Strings in php being delimited by quotes.
   So, if you have a string `username`, it must be written as `"username"`.
   And $_POST[username] become $_POST["username"].
   (and contrary, variables do not need quotes, so, `echo "$msg";` must be `echo $msg;`)
2. all variables must be set or checked for existence. so,
   `if ((!$_POST[username]) || (!$_POST[password])) {`
   must become
   `if (!empty($_POST["username"]) OR !empty($_POST["password"])) {`

With such a code you will see only occasional error and be able to correct it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for takign the time to post that info. will be a great help in the long run. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its the simplest solution. The same thing happened to me. I was running on localhost (wampserver). I found out that my firewall was blocking all cookie requests from localhost. I used ZoneAlarm at the time but I assume other firewalls could have the same effect. Try disabling your firewall to see if it still doesnt work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, I am actually runnign this on a live server.

Comment: a programmer always must go not for the simplest solution but for the debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
try this :
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {

    $db_name = "testDB";
    $table_name = "auth_users";
    $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE username ='".$_POST['username']."' AND password = password('".$_POST['password']."')";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($num != 0) {
            $cookie_name = "auth";
            $cookie_value = "ok";
            $cookie_expire = "0";
            $cookie_domain = "domain.com.au";
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookis_value, $cookie_expire, "/", $cookie_domain, 0);
            $display_block = "
            <p><strong>Secret Menu:</strong></p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=\"secretA.php\">secret page A</a>
                <li><a href=\"secretB.php\">secret page B</a>
            </ul>"; 
        } else {
            header("Location: show_login.html");
            exit;
        };


    }
    else
    {
    header("Location: show_login.html");
    exit;
    };
```

Comment: still the sajme outcome = log in again! thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cookie with php like this:

```
setcookie(<name>,<value>, time()+3600*24);
```

Sometimes, in localhost, the cookies are not set by using: `$_COOKIE[<name>] = <value>`